Files are corrupt on an encrypted APFS sparseimage - hwo to fix?
Good morning to you all -
to save some sensitive business and private data on my internal SSD, I use Disk Utility to format an encrypted APFS sparseimage.
When upgrading from Mojave to Sonoma, I copied all data to an external APFS drive, formated the internal drive and installed Sonoma (clean install) and copied all my stuff back to the home directory.
After mounting the sparseimage I realized, that inside the mounted image about 3 of 7 files where corrupt -
Any file formats on this image are more or less affected.
I do have backups, which were done with CCC - Carbon Copy Cloner. But even those older APFS sparseimages already have some issues with data corruption.

Question 01 <
how to seperate the corrupt files from the still good ones - preferably somehow automated - there are 8200 files and 1600 Folders on the image.


Question 02 <
how can I than merge files and folders into a third destination folder from two different source images and repeat this merging process with as many of the backup images until I come close to the original state of the image?

Or any other suggestions?
Thank you all in advance and best greetings
